# labels in google column charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, google-visualization

I'm using asp c# and followed this tutorial to create google charts http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/create-google-column-chart-from-database-in-Asp-Net-1066.aspx

but I need to add labels to each of the bars in this charts so it looks similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/5bd2Lkyq/

I dont know how or where to add the anotation:

```
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['City', '2010 Population', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, '2000 Population', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work

```
   str.Append("var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);");

    str.Append(" view.setColumns([0,1,{role: 'annotation',type: 'string',calc: 'stringify',  sourceColumn: 1}]);");
```

Then I change data to view

```
 str.Append(" chart.draw(view, options);}");
```